# Given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there's always a rational number $r$ such that $a^r \in (1 - \varepsilon, 1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I wanna show that, for a real number $ a > 1$, and given any $\varepsilon > 0$ there's always a rational number $r$ such that $a^r \in  (1 - \varepsilon, 1)$ and another rational $s$ such that $a^s \in (1, 1 + \varepsilon)$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you find some $n$ such that $n \epsilon >1$?

Comment: I can, yes... How will that help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $ \epsilon>0$. Without loss of generality, take $\epsilon <1$ as well.

If $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then $(1+\epsilon)^n  \ge 1+ n \epsilon$ (prove using 
induction or the binomial theorem).

We can find some $q \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $q \epsilon > a-1$, then $(1+\epsilon)^q >a > 1$.
Since $x \mapsto x^q$ is strictly increasing for $x>0$ (prove using the binomial
theorem) we have $1+ \epsilon > a^{1 \over q} > 1$ (otherwise this will contradict monotonicity of the $x \mapsto x^q$ map).

Since $x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ is strictly decreasing on $(0,\infty)$, we see that
${1 \over 1+ \epsilon} < a^{-{1 \over q}} < 1$, and since
$(1+ \epsilon)(1-\epsilon) = 1 - \epsilon^2 < 1$, we have 
${1 \over 1+ \epsilon} > 1- \epsilon$, and so
$1  -\epsilon < a^{-{1 \over q}} < 1$.

Comment: Neat! Thank you, that's perfect...

Comment: Glad to be able to help!